# Where to download Google Mobile Ads SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

I want add ads to my application.
I made account on AdMob, but next step is download & integrate Google Mobile Ads SDK to Eclipse.
Here is download link
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download?hl=en_US#downloadplay

With no download button. Its comic at all. If i change tab to iOS or WP8 there are .zip to download. But on Android tab there isnt any.

Comment: Please read the notes on the site you linked. There you'll find instructions to setup Google Play services which offer Mobile Ads.

Comment: im lost in this network of links :) and i read it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install them with the SDK manager.
[image]

you also need this dependency (you can add it via maven):
com.google.android.gms:play-services

Answer (score 1):

From that same link:

> Google Mobile Ads is now offered through Google Play services. This is
>   the recommended way of enabling ads on your Android app.

And the instructions to set up Google Play Services is [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest SDK from following this link.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/eclipse#download_the_google_play_services_sdk

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This link 404s for me

Answer (score -1):

Here you can get all the related ads SDK jar file that will be needed for integration to developme mobile app with ads.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk.htm